# Ajax calls in IE8 not showing all data, Works in firefox and IE9

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, firefox, internet-explorer-8

Good evening all!

i have an Ajax call that loads 5 'echo's' from a php script into a div. 
The first echo creates a hidden form field with an ID as the value. 
the rest are superficial and have links to move the div around the page.

In firefox, the full data is loaded, but in IE, it misses out the first echo, to just display the other details. Im missing the hidden element i need as an identifier.

```
//Some other PHP code.....  the * and % in the value are delimiters for splitting a string later.

echo "<input type='hidden' value='*$substept,$subscon%'>";
echo "<a href='javascript:remcol($part)'>.-.</a>".$substept . "<a href='javascript:paddcolumn($part)'>.+.</a> <br> <a href='javascript:mleft($part)'><<</a>" . $subscon . "<a href='javascript:mright($part)'>>></a>";
echo "<br>Column title <br><input type='text' id='title' size = '10'>";
echo "<br>Column width ";
echo "<br><input type='text' id='tb' size = '10'>";
```

How on earth can IE selectively miss out a line of php?! There is absolutely no html for a hidden field. 
Yet. 
This doesn't happen every time. this function is called up to 25 times for 25 different DIVs, and it will work hit an miss in IE.

Checked its inside a form etc.. no idea what's going on!

Example source following 3 calls of this in IE 8:: Check out the Div 03 HTML.

```
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000 1px solid" id=o1>productspgroup<INPUT value=*products,pgroup% type=hidden><A href="javascript:remcol(1)">.-.</A>products<A href="javascript:paddcolumn(1)">.+.</A> <BR><A href="javascript:mleft(1)">&lt;&lt;</A>pgroup<A href="javascript:mright(1)">&gt;&gt;</A><BR>Column title <BR><INPUT id=title size=10><BR>Column width <BR><INPUT id=tb size=10></DIV>
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000 1px solid" id=o2>customerphone1<INPUT value=*customer,phone1% type=hidden><A href="javascript:remcol(2)">.-.</A>customer<A href="javascript:paddcolumn(2)">.+.</A> <BR><A href="javascript:mleft(2)">&lt;&lt;</A>phone1<A href="javascript:mright(2)">&gt;&gt;</A><BR>Column title <BR><INPUT id=title size=10><BR>Column width <BR><INPUT id=tb size=10></DIV>
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000 1px solid" id=o3><A href="javascript:remcol(3)">.-.</A>products<A href="javascript:paddcolumn(3)">.+.</A> <BR><A href="javascript:mleft(3)">&lt;&lt;</A>price<A href="javascript:mright(3)">&gt;&gt;</A><BR>Column title <BR><INPUT id=title size=10><BR>Column width <BR><INPUT id=tb size=10></DIV>
<DIV id=o4></DIV>
<DIV id=o5></DIV>
<DIV id=o6></DIV>
```

After checking syntax as advised::

```
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000 1px solid" id=o1><A href="javascript:remcol(1)">.-.</A> customer <A href="javascript:paddcolumn(1)">.+.</A> <BR><A href="javascript:mleft(1)">&lt;&lt;</A>surname<A href="javascript:mright(1)">&gt;&gt;</A><BR>Column title <BR><INPUT id=title size=10><BR>Column width <BR><INPUT id=tb size=10></DIV>
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000 1px solid" id=o2><INPUT value=*customer,email% type=hidden><A href="javascript:remcol(2)">.-.</A>customer<A href="javascript:paddcolumn(2)">.+.</A> <BR><A href="javascript:mleft(2)">&lt;&lt;</A>email<A href="javascript:mright(2)">&gt;&gt;</A><BR>Column title <BR><INPUT id=title size=10><BR>Column width <BR><INPUT id=tb size=10></DIV>
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000 1px solid" id=o3><INPUT value=*customer,email% type=hidden><A href="javascript:remcol(3)">.-.</A>customer<A href="javascript:paddcolumn(3)">.+.</A> <BR><A href="javascript:mleft(3)">&lt;&lt;</A>email<A href="javascript:mright(3)">&gt;&gt;</A><BR>Column title <BR><INPUT id=title size=10><BR>Column width <BR><INPUT id=tb size=10></DIV>
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #000 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #000 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: #000 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #000 1px solid" id=o4><INPUT value=*customer,email% type=hidden><A href="javascript:remcol(4)">.-.</A>customer<A href="javascript:paddcolumn(4)">.+.</A> <BR><A href="javascript:mleft(4)">&lt;&lt;</A>email<A href="javascript:mright(4)">&gt;&gt;</A><BR>Column title <BR><INPUT id=title size=10><BR>Column width <BR><INPUT id=tb size=10></DIV>
<DIV id=o5></DIV>
```

Javascript:

```
function choosedata(cin){

cot = "so"+cin;
var strr="main.php?func=21&part=" + cin + "&step=" + counter[cin] + "&subs=";
colchange = 'o' + cin;
if (counter[cin] >=2){
strr = strr + document.getElementById(cot).value;
}

callajaxd(strr, colchange);
counter[cin]++;

}


function callajaxd(str,elemin)   //URL String, Box to go in
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById(elemin).innerHTML="";
var back = "";
return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
document.getElementById(elemin).innerHTML="<img src='loading.gif' />";
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
 document.getElementById(elemin).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
 } 



}
xmlhttp.open("GET",str,true);
xmlhttp.send();


}
```

Come home now and using IE9 and it works fine, at least its only IE8 that its happening on,  but i cant install IE8 on a windows 7 pc even in compatibility mode, so short of getting virtualbox out i'll have to continue debugging tomorrow.

Comment: Could you post the javascript?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at `document.getElementById(elemin).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;` does the responseText include the input line?

Comment: the hidden input field doesn't seem to have an id or a name. is that intentional?

Comment: Yes,the hidden field doesn't need to be called by DOM directly. Will breakpoint in a few mins and update you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help and advice on this.
The issue it seems, led with the cPanel hosting account i have. The server was having issues under load. 
My own fault for going for shared hosting! 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, get your syntax exact and add the trailling slash :

```
<input type='hidden' value='*$substept,$subscon%' />
```

IE can be a bitch sometime. But I wouldn't understand why only the first one would be stripped.

Comment: The IE f12 debugger hides trailing slashes... It is there now after the edit though. Cheers for your input!

Answer (score 0):

in your jQuery ajax function try setting the option cache: 'false'

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'blah.php',
    type: 'post',
    cache: 'false'
});
```

or you can append some random time variable to the url, this will trick IE into thinking the page is new and won't use the cached version.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'blah.php?foo=<?php echo time(); ?>'
});
```

Hope this helps... edit: totally misunderstood the question.. figured it was IE caching the ajax calls ;)

Comment: Cheers Dale, i have caching disabled for my browsing session anyway while coding. great idea though, it is something i will implement.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, try wrapping the variables declared within the first echo in curly braces:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' value='*{$substept},{$subscon}%' />";
```

I was thinking along the lines of isolating them from the metachars.

Comment: Will try this when i'm back on an XP machine with IE8. thanks!